# Как передать переменную через роут в посредник Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Есть роут вывода товаров с переменной $id категории, которую надо передать через посредник в контроллер и вывести товары. Посредник проверяет существование такой категории по id. Как передать эту переменную в посредник и обработать ее в нем?

Answer (score 1):

При проверке в посреднике, вы обращаетесь к id через request->id.
В таком случае, если при проверке существовании категории с заданным id, вы получаете истину, значит запрос проходит дальше в контроллер, в котором вы можете обратиться аналогичным образом - через  request->id.